# For loop not looping through all data

Tags: java, for-loop

The `For Loop` is not looping in my codes through all my data. I've read through it thoroughly and still couldn't find any error.

Hope its not some stupid mistake.

Here's a snippet of my `for loop` codes:

```
String convertedDuration= "";
String timeConverted = convertedDuration;

for (int i = 0; i < submissionTime.length; i ++)
    {
        String strDate = submissionTime[i];
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
        Date getDate = sdf.parse(strDate);
        getDate.getTime();
        convertedDuration = timeConverted + (getDate.getTime());
    }

    System.out.println("convertedDuration : "+ convertedDuration);
```

thanks for any help in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

print inside your loop not outside .your are only print last one.move print line to loop.

```
for (int i = 0; i < submissionTime.length; i ++)
        {
            String strDate = submissionTime[i];
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
            Date getDate = sdf.parse(strDate);
            getDate.getTime();
            convertedDuration = timeConverted + (getDate.getTime());
            System.out.println("convertedDuration : "+ convertedDuration);
}
```

Comment: The data still won't loop through. I place the print line to check if it prints out every row of my data. It only prints the first row of data that has been converted.

Comment: then check your `submissionTime` .may be it has only one value